# Is there at least a single English word which starts with the [ʊ] sound?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

[ʊ] is a short vowel sound, as in *good* or *wolf* or *bush*.
Is there at least one word which starts with it in English?

Comment: Do you have any particular dialect in mind?  Different dialects sometimes have very different vowel sounds.

Comment: In Yorkshire English, the poncy southern /ʌ/ is pronounced as a proper manly /ʊ/. So you do get it  **up north** /ʊp nɔːθ/

Comment: @JavaLatte: But even us poncy southerners say ***Oops!*** on those (incredibly rare) occasions when we make a mistake (such as when we think we might have mispronounced ***oophyte**!* :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Umlaut](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/umlaut):

> Pronunciation:
>
> (UK) IPA(key): /ˈʊm.laʊt/, /ˈʌm.laʊt/
>
> (US) IPA(key): /ˈʊm.laʊt/, /ˈum.laʊt/

Comment: Some word you got there

Comment: It was what came to mind.

Comment: not very English though, is it?

Answer (score 4):

[Oopsy-daisy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/oopsy-daisy) (AmE) starts with /ʊ/. And I think it counts as a word—it's in the dictionary.

Comment: And "oops" is another by itself, so you get credit for two words.